# Open Canopy Notebook session in another browser

Tags: enthought, jupyter-notebook

I am running canopy 1.0.3.1262 on ubuntu 12.04. When trying to embed a mpeg 4 video as described in [this tutorial](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/05/12/embedding-matplotlib-animations/), the notebook's output displays `Your browser does not support the video tag.` Is there a way I can connect to the kernel with firefox? Or, alternatively, is there a way I can get the video to play in Canopy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a very convenient way to do it, but you can look at Canopy's log files, to see the URL of the notebook, and open it in a browser.  This work-flow will be simplified in an upcoming release of Canopy.

But, Canopy adds some custom JavaScript to notebooks, to manage saving and make minor modifications to the layout, etc.  Unfortunately, this code seems to assume that the notebook would be opened inside Canopy alone, and causes a failure when the notebook is opened outside Canopy. This bug will be fixed in an upcoming release of Canopy.

Comment: I assume you work for Enthought given your access to information that I haven't been able to find. Any word on supporting HTML 5 videos?

Comment: yes, I do work for Enthought. We ourselves have plans for using HTML5 video within Canopy, and we have been working to fix various issues on different platforms. (Look at http://blog.enthought.com/open-source/fun-with-qtwebkit-html5-video/ for example)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to run the notebook in Firefox without changing your default settings is to just copy and paste the url from the address bar in whichever browser you are using into the address bar in Firefox.

Comment: Canopy doesn't show an address bar when it displays a notebook. I guess they assume you're not going to be using the built in web engine for anything beside displaying ipython notebooks, and as such, do not need an address bar. (Canopy is Enthought's pre-baked, all-in-one python ide)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that canopy had a separate viewer for the notebook. Hmm, alright, if you can find where they put the install directory for Python, you can try adding the folder containing IPython.exe to your path. If you do that, you can try to start the notebook from command line with the command `ipython notebook`. That should open up a notebook in your default browser. If not, try connecting to http://127.0.0.1:8888/ which is the local address it *may* use, depending on how it's configured. It has been a while since I've looked at a canopy install, so those are just suggestions.

Comment: From the command line, Canopy Python and ipython are standard. This article describes how to put them on the PATH if you did not do so on installation: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-s-User-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH- .  As Ian suggested, you can then run `ipython notebook`

Comment: Going to Canopy's bin folder and doing `./ipython notebook` allows me to run a new kernel (who's local address is 127.0.0.1:8888), but doesn't let me connect to an existing kernel. If just Canopy is open, that address and the ports above and below it don't let me connect.

Answer (score 1):

To open a "ipynb" in a browser, right click in a free area of notebook and chose an option (I don't know the difference between then). I use it to view my notebook in "Night mode" in Chrome.

[image: In Canopy - right click]

[image: THAT'S WHAT I MEAN!]